# ExtJS 4.1.1: Custom display text for multi-select combobox

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs4.1, multi-select

I've got a multi-select combobox whose display value I need to set following the particular schema "Selections [x]", where x corresponds to the number of selected items. Unfortunately, after trying it using a number of different approaches I couldn't find a way to achieve the desired result. Using the fieldSubTpl config or overwriting the valueToRaw() method seem to be the most promising approaches to me. However, I couldn't get either of them to work.

I found a working example of the desired behaviour for ExtJS 6 [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1b45&view/editor). If you select more than one value the combobox displays "x values selected" rather than simply concatenating the selected values.

How can I achieve the same result in ExtJS 4.1.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`displayTpl`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/source/ComboBox.html#Ext-form-field-ComboBox) config for [`combo`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox).

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2afp)**, I have created same example in **ExtJS 4.x** as you provide in **ExtJS 6.x**. It is working fine. Hope this will guide you or help you to achieve your required solution.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: 'Multiple Seletion Example in ExtJS 4.x for combo box',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'combo',
        margin: 20,
        fieldLabel: 'Character Name',
        store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['id', 'name'],
            data: [{
                id: 0,
                name: 'John Snow'
            }, {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Tyrion Lannister'
            }, {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Morgan Dexter'
            }, {
                id: 3,
                name: 'Lannister'
            }, {
                id: 4,
                name: 'Silicon Vally'
            }]
        }),
        displayField: 'name',
        /*
        If you use using this then initially you will see {0 values selected}
           displayTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('{[values instanceof Array ? values.length === 1 ? values[0]["' + combo.displayField + '"] : values.length + " values selected" : values]}'),
        */
        valueField: 'id',
        queryMode: 'local',
        multiSelect: true,
        filterPickList: true,
        listeners: {
            render: function (combo) {
                //Use propery {displayTpl}
                //The template to be used to display selected records inside the text field. An array of the selected records' data will be passed to the template.
                combo.displayTpl = new Ext.XTemplate('{[values instanceof Array ? values.length === 1 ? values[0]["' + combo.displayField + '"] : values.length + " values selected" : values]}');
                /*
                you can also use like below function
                combo.displayTpl = new Ext.XTemplate('{[this.getDisplayField(values)]}', {
                    getDisplayField: function (values) {
                        if (Ext.isArray(values)) {
                            var len = values.length;
                            return len == 1 ? values[0].name : (len + ' values selected');
                        }
                        return values;
                    }
                });*/
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works! I also tried using the fiddle example in the past but for whatever reason it did not work back then.

Comment: mostly welcome @TobsenB :). May be something you have missed.